# How can i replace the coordinate point of my diagram with a rectangular point with a certain size (width and length)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is it possible to replace my coordinate point with a rectangular point? The size of this rectangular should be for example 0.1/0.15 (witdh/height)...
How can i solve this problem? Thank you in advance and sorry for my English.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar]
\addplot[
scatter,mark=*,only marks,
point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
]
table {
x y color myvalue
0.5 0.2 1 0.25
0.2 0.1 2 3
0.7 0.6 3 0.75
0.35 0.4 4 0.125
0.65 0.1 5 2
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no rectangular marks available only square marks, but you can scale the square to make it a rectangle. As salim bou points out in his answer, `mark=square*` will give you a square mark. Adding `every mark/.append style={xscale=0.67}` to the plot options will reduce the width of the mark by 33% while keeping the height fixed, making it a rectangle where the width:height ratio is about 1:1.5.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar]
\addplot[
  every mark/.append style={xscale=0.67},
  scatter,mark=square*,mark size={3pt},only marks,
  point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
]
table {
x y color myvalue
0.5 0.2 1 0.25
0.2 0.1 2 3
0.7 0.6 3 0.75
0.35 0.4 4 0.125
0.65 0.1 5 2
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can actually define a new plotmark quite easily. `\pgfdeclareplotmark{rect}{\pgfpathrectangle
    {\pgfqpoint{-1.5\pgfplotmarksize}{-\pgfplotmarksize}}
   {\pgfqpoint{3.5\pgfplotmarksize}{2\pgfplotmarksize}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke}` etc.

Comment: More flexibility can be added of course.

Answer (score 4):

Just change to `mark=square*`, key `mark size={dim}` allows to set marker sizes to `dim`, For circular markers, `dim` is the
radius, for other plot marks it is about half the width and height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar]
\addplot[
scatter,mark=square*,mark size={3pt},only marks,
point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
]
table {
x y color myvalue
0.5 0.2 1 0.25
0.2 0.1 2 3
0.7 0.6 3 0.75
0.35 0.4 4 0.125
0.65 0.1 5 2
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you need rectangle mark with non equal width and height you can create new mark with `mark=text` then `text mark={\rule{width}{height}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar]
\addplot[
scatter,mark=text, text mark={\rule{2mm}{2.5mm}},only marks,
point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
]
table {
x y color myvalue
0.5 0.2 1 0.25
0.2 0.1 2 3
0.7 0.6 3 0.75
0.35 0.4 4 0.125
0.65 0.1 5 2
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: thank you for your solution so much but how can i define the size of this square?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Lin asks for *rectangular* marks, not square ones. One quick hack would be something like `\begin{tikzpicture}[every mark/.append style={xscale=0.67}]`, but perhaps you know a better way.

Comment: Your idea  @TorbjørnT. is the better can you post it as answer.